# How to create a Pivot table format Using PHp MySql

Tags: php, mysql, excel, pivot-table

I wanna create a pivot table format. I have the update_by_id and campaign_id in the same table. please see the attached image.
[image]

I need this format

[image]

Group By Updated by id and Campaign Id with Lead id total. please check and let me know.

New attached image 
[image]

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: https://evolt.org/node/26896

Comment: Thanks Sure I will take care of it next time.

Comment: Good tutorial link @JayBlanchard would be even better when the topicstarter replaces the deprecated mysql_* functions with mysqli_* functions or PDO.

Comment: Yeah - it is an oldie @RaymondNijland ;-)

Comment: Yes i know i saw the topic date @JayBlanchard

Comment: Please see the attached image not able to get the count of campaign group by username and campaign both